# Error in pom.xml while import hadoop in eclipse using maven(m2e)

Tags: eclipse, maven, hadoop, eclipse-plugin

I'm trying to add some feature in Hadoop right now. I got error after I import Hadoop sourcecode to eclipse. Most of the projects are error because POM.xml.

I was clean the all project for many times and still got those error. The error is like this:
[image]

My spesification:

1. Eclipse Juno for android
2. hadoop-2.5.0-src.tar.gz

Could you tell me, how to solve this problem? Thanks

Comment: You could have used google to find an answer: http://wiki.eclipse.org/M2E_plugin_execution_not_covered

Comment: Hi @khmarbaise thanks pointing me those link.. I'll take a look on it.

Comment: @khmarbaise, Sorry I am not really sure about what should I do here.. Is the solution are put <ignore/> tag in <parent> ? I'm still confuse about it. I still got error with that. Please explain me what should I do. Thanks